# Understanding an op-amp modulator circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, modulation, amplitude-modulation

I'm trying to understand an op-amp modulator circuit I came across in a book. The circuit uses switches. According to the book, switches S1 and S4 are on during the positive half cycle of the carrier waveform, and S2 and S3 are on during the negative half cycle.

I have drawn what I think the circuit simplifies to in the negative and positive half cycle respectively by replacing the on switches with short circuits and the off switches with open circuits.

However, I'm wondering if I have made a mistake, since these drawings do not explain how the circuit works. In particular, the book says that one of the op-amps is a summer that adds waveforms V3 and V4. According to my diagrams, V3 and V4 are connected to the summer during the negative half cycle as expected, but not during the positive half cycle.

I have included my drawings and a photo of the circuit diagram in the book. In my drawings, I have left out the op amp that drives the switches.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not use a simulation tool. They are free and reliable and everyone who's anyone in EE is using them.

Comment: I have a mathematical background so my brain is wired to think that I should be able to work it out from first principles.

Comment: Vc just toggles between 0 and 180 deg phase shift between Vm and Vo.

Comment: What frequency is the carrier? The LM324 works poorly above 10kHz.

Answer (score 1):

The modulating signal vm, is amplified by the adjustable inverting amplifier A1. The output, 180° out of phase with respect to the input, is sampled by the CD4016/4 and amplified by A3 (inverting). The sampled and amplified signal must be added with any sampled signal coming from S3-S4 from the inverting adder made up of A4, R10, 11 and 12.
[image]

Comment: Especially useful, because this does identify A4 as 'the summer'.

Answer (score 0):

Your second diagram has the R7/R11 junction grounded when Vc is low, which is wrong.

When Vc is high Vo is Vf multiplied by a positive constant kp

When Vc is low Vo is Vf multiplied by a negative constant kn

Where

kp = \$\frac{R_{12}}{R_{10}}\cdot\frac{R_9}{R_6+R_8}\$

kn = \$-\frac{R_{12}}{R_7+R_{11}}\$

You would normally pick values such that kp = -kn, for example
if all the resistors in the above equations were 10kΩ except R12 = 20kΩ the gain would be +1 or -1.